# Is Metasploit software primarily used for programming?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

The [metasploit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metasploit) tag seems rather messy. I can see how there can be programming questions related to it (like errors in actual custom exploit code). However, a lot of questions tagged with it seem to be about *using* it, like about why something isn't working when doing something with the software.

So, is it a programming tool in the sense, that merely using it is on-topic at Stack Overflow?

Or is it just general computer software in the sense, that questions tagged with it, which don't clearly indicate how they are about programming, should be closed?

In the latter case, would it be reasonable to edit the tag description to warn that many Metasploit questions are off-topic?

Comment: Unfamiliar with this: can you link to both an on topic and off topic question? (Note: My fellow Meta's, you can look - but try to not vote on either! Unless you *are* familiar with this framework and indeed *do* find one of these to have clear merits or demerits.)

Comment: Well, here's a recent example question, which *I* think is off-topic, but perhaps someone can explain how it is on-topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39843884/metasploit-synflood-not-working

Comment: ...and actually there are surprisingly few questions which *I* think are clearly on-topic, but here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38554567/cant-make-symbol-in-php

Comment: It seems to be *primarily* used (at least on SO) by script kiddies who wouldn't know an MVCE if you hit them over the head with it.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Yeah, though seems to me there are also a lot of students in computer security courses, trying to do their homework/coursework.

Comment: About the only thing I've seen under there that could be considered close to on-topic is http://stackoverflow.com/q/38205729/50447. Every other question I've seen either has close votes or is closed

Comment: In my opinion - in the context of this site - Metasploit is a Ruby framework

Comment: @RowlandShaw and even then, you can replace metaexploit with "my friend" and the question still makes sense. It isn't a metaexploit question, in the way that it isn't about the framework itself, but about programming techniques.

Comment: Why is http://stackoverflow.com/q/38554567/2564301 closed for not containing a reproducible MCVE? (Just curious. [The timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38554567/timeline) shows the CVing started about 12 hours ago when it appeared in a Review, so *probably* unrelated to this meta question.)

Answer (score 19):

Metasploit is a framework for testing security vulnerabilities. It was created to more easily convert CVE's into exploit code, so that if a new CVE came out, one could quickly test if one was vulnerable.

So programming is part of Metasploit; both for the creation of new items, and for the payloads to be sent to a target machine.

This means that the tag itself is applicable for Stack Overflow, but we should add a few warnings:

1. If one's question is about *using* Metasploit, then it should go on our sister site [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com).
2. If one's question is about attacking a specific system, such questions are off-topic on Information Security unless they demonstrate an understanding of the concepts involved and clearly identify a specific problem.

I have added these warnings in an edit suggestion to the tag wiki. I have also added a warning that we do not endorse activities where one uses such tools without permission from the target.

Comment: "I have added these warnings [...] to the tag wiki" [hahahaha](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114/213575)

Comment: @Braiam Tell me about it... but until that feature request of yours gets implemented, there's not much else we can do. Well, apart from voting and commenting vigilantly, of course.

Comment: When did *tools used primarily by programmers* suddenly become off-topic on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Metasploit is primarily used by IT security experts, rather than programmers. But maybe I should rephrase "using Metasploit" in this answer as "using it for vulnerability testing", or something to that effect.

Comment: It's hard to imagine how that doesn't directly impact software developers.  That an IT Security Expert would be executing the tool rather than the actual software developer seems like a distinction without a difference.  Strictly speaking, all software developers should have at least some knowledge and awareness of security issues.  If a software developer were running the tool, would that make the question  on-topic?

Comment: @RobertHarvey We could say similar things about many tools. I thought my answer made it clear that some Metasploit issues are on-topic on SO. If  a question is about an actual vulnerability test, though, it probably belongs on Security.SE . I'm open to suggestions for a better wording.

Comment: Your logic seems reasonable.  I'm just always skeptical about these kinds of intricate scope rules; nobody understands them (they're often perceived as *arbitrary*), nobody reads the guidance, and they're impossible to enforce anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey are you talking about the [algo] tag?

Comment: @Braiam: Well, ALGO is the name of an actual programming language, and the [tag:algorithm] tag wiki doesn't specify any special instructions for its use (other than people apparently having difficulty spelling the actual word).

Comment: As one of the mods on Security, I'd like to say thanks! This is a useful definition. Have an upvote!

Comment: I approved your tag wiki edit, and changed the Usage excerpt.

Answer (score 3):

Saying that Metasploit isn't software primarily used for programming is like saying that CakePHP isn't software primarily used for programming, since both are frameworks. Of course, Metasploit is a *very specialized* framework, but a ruby framework at the end of the day. So, if you can fulfill these two conditions, asking a question that is:

- a specific programming problem, and
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to **software development**

related to metasploit, it's probably on topic.

You can ask programming problems because you are programming exploits, and software (malware) development, despite the insidious and undesirable that it is, is a given.

To answer the question you meant to ask: Yes, metasploit questions can be perfectly on topic for the site... given that you actually meet our quality standards.

Comment: An example of question I'd like to know if it is on-topic: "How to install working Metasploit system on X". If Metasploit is primarily a programming tool, then that is on-topic (assuming a specific concrete problem, error messages etc included, so it is not too broad or unclear). If not, then it is a general computer software question and off-topic.

Comment: @hyde if you read my answer, I don't even refer to metasploit as "programming tool" to support my argument, I said that you can have programming problems with it and these problems are unique to software development. Installing tool X, even if it's gcc, is not **unique** to software development. As I said before: you have to fulfill **two** conditions for your question to be on topic, one isn't enough.

Comment: Let me put it another way: can there be on-topic question with just Metasploit tag? Because there certainly can be such question for, say, *gcc*. Example: question about order of command line options and how they affect linking. Could there be similar on-topic question about how to invoke Metasploit?

Comment: @hyde its a bit of a grey area, but GCC is a compiler; its inherently involved in the process of programming itself. Metasploit is something you can build on with programming, but just using it doesn't mean you're programming. Lots of people download it and fire off penetration tests (or they're script kiddies) with zero knowledge of programming.
I agree with others that its better left for Information Security.

Comment: @hyde by the same analogy, would you expect questions that only have the [tag:excel] tag asked on SO and be on topic? As long as you have a "unique to software development" question, and fulfill any of the other three criteria, you are in the clear, topically speaking.

Comment: Sounds like you read my question if I am asking wether Metasploit questions are generally off-topic? I'm implying no such thing! I'm asking if Metasploit is more like Gcc (asking about problems just running a compiler is on-topic) or like Excel (asking about problems just running an office program is off-topic, even if macro programming questions etc are ok).

Comment: @hyde and I'm challenging that analogy. Look, you simply can't say something is on topic or not only taking into account if it's something commonly used by programmers or if it's a programming tool, that's incredibly shallow and has many troubles scaling up. I'm offering a totally different approach that is more flexible and can be easily generalized to a myriad situations. Once you *stop trying to categorize tools* as being on topic or not, you would be able to tell whenever or not a question is on topic.

Comment: Well, thinking in terms of "what is the task the question is about" would be another way to look at it. Then this question becomes, are the tasks usually asked about under Metasploit tag programming tasks or not. But the tool matters. Asking about setting up remote debugging connection with gdb is on-topic, asking about setting up backdoor with Metasploit IMO isn't, even though technically these are very very similar.

Comment: @hyde err... but is everything and anything you do with metasploit off topic? As Barth said in his answer "**programming is part of Metasploit**; both for the creation of new items, and for the payloads to be sent to a target machine", so using blanket statements about *the tool* isn't possible, so focusing on the task at hand is more precise. The criteria becomes "is this guy programming or not?" which is more obvious.